# How to transfare owner ship of disk folder to non domain account?

Tags: google-workspace, drive

I would like to transfer a folder owner permission to a non domain account. 
But there is an issue which doesn't allow me to do it for non-owned accounts.

How could I transfer the permission?

Comment: How are you doing this? via API or via the 'Transfer ownership' option?

Comment: @YancyGodoy via Transfer ownership.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation here](https://support.google.com/supportu/answer/2402998?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctransferring-ownership-between-domains) changing ownership from a Google Workspace account to a regular non Google Workspace one is not doable and this is `This is expected behavior.`  So the issue you are getting is normal due to security restrictions.

A workaround to this would be to download the file to your computer and share it directly with the external recipient.